# send html email

Tags: email

I want to know if it's possible to send an html email which contains an html quiz, the receiver will fill in the quiz and send it back.  Then, is it possible to see their answers?

Comment: Your question is way too broad. You need to be more specific for us to help you with. in-short: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Can you open the email and see the answers?

Comment: I don't think c# is a relevant tag for this question. But I don't see why it should be closed as 'not a real question' either.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to make a quiz in google docs and invite everyone by email.

Any script in an email will probably be blocked by firewalls, antivirus programs and email readers.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. For sending email , you need to use atleast one server -side scripting language e.g. Asp.net , Php etc.

its a very common requirement and source codes are available easily.